# What should be the result of "c -= --c - c++;" in C Language?

Tags: c

I am trying the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c =0;
    c -= --c - c++;
    printf("%d \n",c);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled and run it using a online c complier (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php) the result is -1. But I expected it to be 0. 
So, I try it on my local Dev C++ (Windows) and the result is 0.

1. Should the result be 0 ?
2. If so, why 2 gcc compilers (ok they are in different plataform) gives me 2 different results ?

I ve been looking for some kind of automatic flag otimization which could produce a different result but I had no success.

Comment: Undefined behaviour.

Comment: "What should be the result of "c -= --c - c++;"?" your coworkers hitting you with a big club.

Comment: It's like there's a fountain somewhere spewing out an endless spew of the same question about multiple increment operators

Answer (score 4):

THIS IS UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR (3 modifications without sequence points inbetween to the same variable)